# C++ library to send back simple string for HTTPS queries

Tags: c++, sockets, poco-libraries

I have an emulator program written in C++ running on Ubuntu 12.04. There are some settings and options needed for running the program, which are given by the main's arguments. I need to query these options via HTTPS from a remote machine/mobile device (so basically imagine I want to return main's arguments). I was wondering if someone can help me with that.

There should probably be some libraries for the ease, for example Poco. I'm not sure how suitable it is for my case, but here is any example of connection setup in poco. It's **not a must** to use any libraries though; just the most efficient/simplest way.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you want here. Are you looking for a way to start a service with specific arguments remotely? Or are you looking for a remote control for the already running service? Regardless, your code snippet doesn't seem to mesh well with your question and I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: @Avery Oh, at this moment I just want to query, no control, after the program runs. So a client device wants to query some of the variables inside my program. And this communitarian should be via HTTPS. Forget about the code above; I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

[Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) (or the non-GPL fork [Civetweeb](https://github.com/bel2125/civetweb)) are embedded web servers. Very easy to set up and add controllers for (typically a half dozen lines of code)

Just add the project file (1 c file) to your project and build, add a line to start the server listening and give it what options you like, and add a callback function to handle requests. It does ssl out of the box (though IIRC you'll need to have openssl installed too)

There was another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405811/high-performance-application-webserver-in-c-c) with some comparisons.  I used civetweb at work, and was impressed at how easy it all was. There's not too much documentation though.

Comment: Ummm, interesting. One thing another user suggested was that if I just want to return a few simple strings via https, there is no need to use https server setup which makes it too complicated. Im very new to it; can you share an example maybe? Just assume you have a main program, listen to the connection, and return main's args.

Comment: civetweb comes with a couple of [example programs.](https://github.com/bel2125/civetweb/blob/master/examples/embedded_c/embedded_c.c)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stripped-down POCO version, for full code see [HTTPSTimeServer example](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/NetSSL_OpenSSL/samples/HTTPSTimeServer/src/HTTPSTimeServer.cpp).

```
struct MyRequestHandler: public HTTPRequestHandler
{
  void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
  {     
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    // ... do your work here

    std::ostream& ostr = response.send();
    ostr << "<html><head><title>HTTPServer example</title>"
         << "<body>Success!</body></html>";
  }
};

struct MyRequestHandlerFactory: public HTTPRequestHandlerFactory
{
  HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler(const HTTPServerRequest& request)
  {
    return new MyRequestHandler;
  }
};

// ...

// set-up a server socket
SecureServerSocket svs(port);
// set-up a HTTPServer instance (you may want to new the factory and params
// prior to constructing object to prevent the possibility of a leak in case
// of exception)
HTTPServer srv(new MyRequestHandlerFactory, svs, new HTTPServerParams);
// start the HTTPServer
srv.start();
```

Comment: Are you sure that is this simple?! where is port defined? And btw, is it just HTTP? 
OK, imagine I want to return main's arguments.

Comment: Yes, I am sure; POCO is all about making things simple and C++ programmer's life easier. As mentioned above, this is a stripped-down version of the HTTPTimeServer example. The only downside of the built-in POCO HTTP(S) server is that it is thread-based so it will not scale gracefully to thousands of concurrent connections.