# creating rest webservice in c/c++ accepting JSON

Tags: c++, json, rest, webservice-client

can anyone please suggest me some good link to create rest webservice accepting JSON in c/c++.

I want my webservice to accept JSON, do some modifications on the received JSON and send the modified JSON to another rest webservice.

Comment: This is one of those questions where if someone asks it, it means that they will not be able to do it. You can start by reading the [formal specifications of the HTTP protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616). Which is a few hundred pages. Then you need to learn all about socket programming. Then you need to write a library that parses JSON. Once having done that, you can finally start working on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the first answer : 
[How to Create Restful Web Services using c++ language and JSON Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057819/how-to-create-restful-web-services-using-c-language-and-json-parser)

It gives multiple libraries for what you're looking as well as JSON parsing library

For JSON I personally have used https://github.com/nlohmann/json which i found very simple and well explained

Hope this gives you some guidance

Comment: I tried using nlohmann json with libcurl but i am unable to get the json data into a json variable. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: I figured out the problem, the hostname was not getting interpreted for my server.